# dijit.Menu to be displayed after DOM had been set up

Tags: dojo, javascript-framework

I have set up in Javascript my preferred dijit.Menu which is that far so good.

How am I able to display the dijit.Menu directly after the page starts up in the  (with it's position) without any mouse interaction?! I have looked in the API so far and don't find the answers. Will I have to "overwrite" a method?

If yes, which one is it? And what do I have todo???

Answer (score 0):

The widget will not show up until it is parsed by dojo.
You should place fake menu markup inside its dom node:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Menu">
   <h1>This text is shown after the dom is loaded 
       and until the menu is parsed and renered</h1>
</div>
```

As soon as menu is ready, everything you've placed inside menu's dom node will be replaced by actual widget's html.

Answer (score 0):

NON-AMD Version:

```
dojo.ready(function(){
// The code for all items!
})
```

DOJO-AMD Version, put the parameters of the modules you like to add, in require as well give them a name in the functions parameters list:

```
require(["dojo/domReady!"],function(){
//natve code
});
```